# EF CodeFirst creating additional Column don't understand why

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got a class "Friend"

```
    public class Friend
{
    [Key , Column(Order = 0)]
    public string MeID { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Me { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string MyFriendID { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser MyFriend { get; set; }

    public bool isFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

when creating the database , It adds an additional column "ApplicationUser_Id" , anyone got a reasonable explanation for why is it doing that ?

i'm sorry if it's a beginners question.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it is the primary key for `ApplicationUser` which is the type for your property `MyFriend`

Comment: @user3185569 have you got any idea what to do to get rid of this ApplicationUser_Id column ?

Comment: Yes . Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a relationship column. `Friend` has-a `ApplicationUser`. So for that relationship to be implemented, the database table `Friend` has to have a foreign key `ApplicationUser_Id` which is the Primary Key for type `ApplicationUser`.

To get rid of that column, you can use the `[NotMapped]` attribute:

```
[NotMapped]
public ApplicationUser MyFriend { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `[ForeignKey("MyFriendID")]` attribute to `MyFriend` property and `[ForeignKey("MeID")]` to `Me` property

If you use C# 6 you can use `nameof(MyFriendID)` instead of hard-coded string "MyFriendID" (suggested by @TGlatzer)

Comment: And use "[ForeignKey(nameof(MyFriendId))]" instead